# fprintf and characters from string

Tags: c, function, file, printf

I'm having this weird issue while trying to make a function to write some structure fields to a file called `"providers.txt"`, the structure has three `fields: char code[5], char name[50] and char phone[12]`.

Also, I have to follow this i/o format:

```
input:
code: TEST
name: Jordan Maker
phone: 02418380828

output(in file):
TEST<tab>(0241) 838.08.28<tab>Jordan Maker
```

The data `load(field filling)` is just fine when I test it with the `printProvider` function, so it's not the structure that's causing the problem, though.

this is the function:

```
int saveProviderinFile(Provider p, FILE *out)
{
int i;
out = fopen("providers.txt", "w");

if(out == NULL) return 0;
else
{
    fprintf(out, "%s\t(", p.code);
    for(i=0; i<=3;i++)fprintf(out, "%c", p.phone[i]);
    fprintf(out, ") ");
    for(i=4; i<=6;i++)fprintf(out, "%c", p.phone[i]);
    fprintf(out, ".");
    for(i=7; i<=8;i++)fprintf(out, "%c", p.phone[i]);
    fprintf(out, ".");
    for(i=9; i<=10;i++)fprintf(out, "%c",p.phone[i]);
    fprintf(out, "\t%s\n", p.name);
    return 1;
    }

}
```

Don't mind the return value, it's just made to verify that the file opening was successful or not.

The result in `providers.txt` looks like this:

TEST() ..Jordan Rules

As you can see, it doesn't print the phone in the file, but it does print it in the console, even when i say `fprintf` instead of `printf`.

I'm new to stackoverflow, so excuse me if I committed some mistake in the question format. Also, excuse my bad english.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is the filling procedure.

```
    void buildProvider(Provider *p, char code[], char name[], char phone[])
{
    strcpy(p->code, code);
    strcpy(p->name, name);
    strcpy(p->phone, phone);
}
```

And this is the print procedure, which prints the format just fine:

```
void printProvider(Provider p)
{
    int i;

    if(strcmp(p.code, "0000") != 0) 
    {
        printf("%s\t(", p.code);
        for(i=0; i<=3;i++)printf("%c", p.phone[i]);
        printf(") ");
        for(i=4; i<=6;i++)printf("%c", p.phone[i]);
        printf(".");
        for(i=7; i<=8;i++)printf("%c", p.phone[i]);
        printf(".");
        for(i=9; i<=10;i++)printf("%c", p.phone[i]);
        printf("\t%s\n", p.name);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Provider not found\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your printing of phone looks correct, so we'll need to see where you fill it in.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. My vars are in spanish, but I translated it to english for you to read and understand it easier, haha.

Comment: Are you calling `saveProviderinFile` in a loop by any chance? `fopen` with mode `w` will truncate the file each time and start writing from the beginning of the file. Also, you say the input name is "Jordan Maker" but then output shows "Jordan Rules". Is that intentional?

Comment: Don't forget to close files in the function that opens the file.

Comment: Jonathan, I forgot about that, thanks!. The problem persists, though.

Comment: @kaylum , no, it's not in a loop. and I fixed the Rules thing.

Comment: As I know, there are no obvious reasons that can make `fprintf` print characters in the console, so please make sure that your code has been compiled successfully after being modified. You can check this by adding something like `putchar('$');` in your code.